# Different way to write LDRB

Tags: assembly, arm, disassembly

So I'm writing up some ARM code, and we were told to disassemble a program, and then recode it using what we know. The problem is I keep coming across as LDRB command, of which I know nothing about. Going through the ARM documentation, it seems to offset the value by one byte? How could I recode this in simple ARM, even though it'll take more lines?

Comment: ldr is a word load 32 bits, ldrh is a halfword 16 bits, ldrb is a byte 8 bits and ldrd if you have it is a double word 64 bits

Answer (score 3):

`LDRB` loads a single byte from memory into a register.  I don't think there's any way to simplify that operation further.

Here's a link to the ARM docs for the [`LDR` instruction](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489c/CIHDGFEG.html).